# Google FCM Request

Tags: api

I'm working on the Google FCM message service. I deploy my API with my server it's working fine. But when I do the same within Client Production Service it gives me 401 error.

I'm running Window Service and hitting Restful API. I validate each and everything within Google account also but not able to rectify the same.

Answer (score 1):

I've recently the same problem. I implemented everything right with all parameters. Finally I found the solution. I used the API Key from [Google developer console](https://console.developers.google.com/) and not from firebase. So go to the following url: `https://console.firebase.google.com/project/YOUR_PROJECT_ID/settings/cloudmessaging/`

[image: Cloud Messaging Settings]

There you can see two API keys. Choose the longer top server key.

After I replaced the key in the header `Authorization: key=YOUR_KEY`, it finally works.